# Bootstrap right alignment not working as expected

Tags: bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4:
I have a Card-Header with a label and a icon, I want the Label left aligned and the icon right aligned, but the icon ist always attached at the label. Why its not working as I would expect?
When adding col-8 to the h6 and col-4 to the div class there is still a large space from the icon to the right border.

This is my code:

```
     <div class="card-header" style="margin:unset;padding:unset">
        <div class="row" style="margin:unset">
            <h6 class="mt-1">@list.Name</h6>
            <div class="text-right">
                <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-file-import"></i>
                </span>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `<div>` instead of `<h6>`, as `<h6>` tag will have its default margin values in browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="card-header" style="margin:unset;padding:unset">
        <div class="row" style="margin:unset">
            <div class="">@list.Name</div>
            <div class="text-right">
                <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-file-import"></i>
                </span>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. If you add col-8 to the h6 and col-4 to the div class, default bootstrap's padding will be also applied. Add class `p-0` to both div to cancel those padding.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add each element like h6 and icon in separate div with class='col'

See the following example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>  
  <div class="card-header" style="margin:unset;padding:unset">
        <div class="row" style="margin:unset">
          <div class="col">
            <h6 class="mt-1">@list.Name</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="col text-right">
            <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-file-import"></i>
            </span>   
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```